# Does anyone actually use randsequence in their verification environments?

Tags: system-verilog

If does, could you please give an example of when `randsequence` is preferred over other methods?

Comment: Try to search internet. There is a bunch of examples.

Comment: Off course I've seen examples on internet, but they only explain how to use it...  I could not find why and when randsequence is preffered over using the regular sequences. Also I've searched randsequence in the entire verification environment at my work place and in VIPs bought from other companies and it was never used there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say *other methods*, I assume you mean UVM sequences. It is not a question of one over the other; they are not exclusive. You can certainly use a `randsequence` in the body of a UVM sequence.

The reason you don't see it that often is most design verification engineers are not software programmers and `randsequence` provides an alternative way of codifying a procedural flow that is very different from the way most people have been taught procedural programming. It works very well for rigid protocols and instruction set stream.

Probably a big factor preventing it from being more widely adopted is int is not an extendable construct that fits in well with OOP programming.

Answer (score 1):

What I particularly like about it is it's readability and structured randomness. You can quickly create interesting sequences to explore your design and the code structure looks a bit like a state machine. It's difficult to achieve this without randsequence.

You can find a nice article on it here: [design-reuse.com](https://www.design-reuse.com/articles/42150/randsequence-systemverilog-s-unsung-hero.html#)

Once you get familiar with it you'll use it regularly